# 404 error when calling function in Flask app

Tags: python, json, flask

I am loading data from a JSON file and returning a template with this function in Flask:

```
import json
def template():
    with open(PERSONAL_DATA, "r") as info:
        info = json.load(info)
    return render_template("temp.html", title="Info",
                           header=str(info[name])) event you have.")
```

But when I call this function from my app, I get a 404 page. The function is in the main file, and it runs fine on it's own.

Comment: What's the full error message? Also, you can see from the syntax highlighting in your question, that you have an error right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't wrap the function in an app route decorator. See this [Flask URL registration documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#url-route-registrations) for more info.

```
@app.route("/template", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def template():
    with open(PERSONAL_DATA, "r") as info:
        info = json.load(info)
    return render_template("temp.html", title="Info",
                           header=str(info[name]))
```

Also, import json at the top of the file, not right before you use it.